# Disable mouse scroll with Scrollview in Kivy

Tags: scrollview, kivy

I have a GridLayout with some images inside a ScrollView. Something like this:

```
ScrollView:
    GridLayout:
        Image:
        Image:
        ...
```

I want to scroll the Scrollview when the left mouse button is pressed and "drag" (make a copy of the image that follows the mouse position) when the right mouse button is pressed.
Actually, when I drag the image the scrollview comes together.

Is there a way to disable the scroll only for right clicks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your own ScrollView class (`class YourClass(ScrollView):`), and override `on_touch_down` etc. to do whatever you like. Information like the mouse button is included as properties of the touch, documented [here](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.input.motionevent.html).

As an example, [here](https://github.com/inclement/kivent-game/blob/master/main.py#L117) is some code I have that does different things depending on what mouse button is pressed.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was searching for.  =)